# Rest using @QueryParam with @POST or @PUT

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm using jersey API for some REST web services with apache Tomcat. I need to pass more than one parameter to a method so I decided to use @QueryParam annotation like this :

```
@GET
@Path("/date")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDate(@QueryParam("id") String Id, @QueryParam("inDate") String inDate)
{
...
}
```

when I call it like this everything works. But when I use annotaitions @POST or @PUT instead of @GET then it shows an error:

> HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
>
> message Method Not Allowed
>
> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested
>   resource (Method Not Allowed).

Is it possible to user this with POST or PUT and how?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you just need to make the request using POST or PUT. This can't be done via the URL - you'd need a specific client (for example the http resource firefox plugin) that can send requests with methods other than GET. Note that for POST you can also use [`@FormParam`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html)

Comment: Great, I've tried with Poster plug-in and works. Thank you very much!